# Positioning CSS Sprites as background images

Tags: css, css-sprites, sprite, background-position

I am using icons as background images for titles etc and I am using **background-position** already to align them correctly so when I want to replace the background images with the appropriate slices of the sprite I can no longer position the backgrounds correctly, is there a solution?

I do not want to animate it (other than changing once on hover) just to position the sliced sprite as a background even though the background-position has already been taken:

**.beautifu1-gallery { background-position: -130px 0;  }**

Now I want to add another background-position on to the same div.

Adding another div might work, but it is not as elegant as I want a solution to be.

Edited Comment: Sprites do not seem to be practical to me, even if the amount request goes down substantially - should I therefore code all my icons as seperate images? When marking them up as backgrounds is clearly easier - which what they are - illustrative backgrounds to the titles, to the navigation, to the images and to the downloadable materials. Adding another div seems also as an waste of energy. Are developers to blame that the way internet works is still around text based information and nobody seems to be even thinking of how to transfer multiple images, video, graphics, animation efficiently from the user to server or the other way around?

This is porn not development - trying to plug every hole that can be seen without thought of the overall picture.

Alright - I just googled out of frustration and found out what Data URIs and MHTML are. Game over!

Comment: maybe another div would do the trick?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? We don't know if you want to animate the image or move it around the div...

Comment: The clause beginning with "I am using background-position already" is very confusing and probably preventing you from getting an answer. Imagine that we don't know anything (because we don't). :)

Comment: Could you please post some more of your code? It's really hard to see what the problem is you're experiencing with so little to go on. :-/